# How to stop a certain part of html page from scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to copy the twitter websites homepage but I have a problem with the side section scrolling.

This is the right side section I created/copied from twitter homepage right side section

[image]

and it won't stop scrolling until it reaches the max height of the page, I also tried setting the height/max-height to it's only true height (1308px) and it doesn't work.

I only use HTML and CSS by the way and does not want to put JS. Is there a solution using only HTML and CSS?

Comment: You can provide your code so that people can help you identity the issue. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679

Comment: Try `overflow-y: hidden;` in your the element that is scrollable, this will disable the scrolling on that element

Answer (score 1):

in your html:

```
<div id="footer">some elements here</div>
```

and in your css:

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Also we can add z-index too for further properties. Here @Ehsan 's answer:  [JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/muratgokoglu/7o5r9j3h/)